# SQL syntax error in sql query

Tags: mysql, syntax-error

I have this query:

```
SELECT `post`.`id` AS `posts_id,
       `categories`.`id` AS `category_id`,
       `title`,
       `contents`,
       `date_posted`,
       `categories`.`name
  FROM `post`
 INNER JOIN `categories` ON `categories`.`id` = `post`.`cat_id`
```

And it yields this error:

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near:
>
> > 'categories`.`id`AS`category_id`,`title`,`contents`,`date_posted`,`cat' at line 1

Comment: Please, make a more descriptive question title.

Comment: Don't expect us to click links we can't trust - post (the relevant part of) the query here instead. **EDIT**: Just like Tomalak has done for you.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing backticks ` at various locations:

```
SELECT `post`.`id` AS `posts_id`, `categories`.`id` AS `category_id`,
    `title`,`contents`,`date_posted`,`categories`.`name`
    FROM `post`
    INNER JOIN `categories` ON `categories`.`id` = `post`.`cat_id`
```

Answer (score 1):

You have forgotten to end "`".

Try this:

```
SELECT `post`.`id` AS `posts_id`, `categories`.`id` AS `category_id`,
        `title`,`contents`,`date_posted`,`categories`.`name`
        FROM `post`
        INNER JOIN `categories` ON `categories`.`id` = `post`.`cat_id`
```